# passing arguments to a function for double integration in R

Tags: r, function, statistics, integration

I have the following code

```
 f1 <- function (v1) {
    v1^(beta1-1)*exp(-(lambda1*v1)^beta1-(lambda0*(vv/LC-v1))^beta1)
    }

f2 <- function (v2) {
    v2^(beta1-1)*exp(-(lambda1*v2)^beta1-(lambda0*(vv/UC-v2))^beta1)
    }

F_r <- function (vv) {
    (1+exp(-(lambda1*vv/LC)^beta1)-exp(-(lambda1*vv/UC)^beta1) 
      -beta1*lambda1^beta1* 
              ( integrate(f1,lower=0,upper=vv/LC)$value+
                integrate(f2,lower=0,upper=vv/UC)$value) )* 
              (b1^a1/gamma(a1))*vv^(a1-1)*exp(-b1*vv)
    }

lambda0<-lambda1<-0.01

beta0<-beta1<-1

LC<-0.2
-UC<-1.2

>a1<-2
>b1<-1

integrate(F_r,lower=0,upper=Inf)$value
```

Since f1 and f2 are function of vv, so i don't know whether it should be inside F_r or outside. However, the value of F_r should be lies between 0 and 1. If f1 and f2 are outside F_r i have following message

```
 ##Error in f(x, ...) : object 'vv' not found##
```

Comment: You're missing the definition of `b1` and `a1`. You need to provide `vv` to your functions `f1` and `f2` for them to be able to use it, by adding `vv` to their function signatures and passing it along through the `integrate` call.

Comment: i assigned values to a1 and b1 respectively, but still it is not working

Comment: Add ", vv" to both of your calls to `integrate`, e.g. `integrate(f1,lower=0,upper=vv/LC, vv)` and add it to the function signature of `f1` and `f2`, e.g. `f1 <- function (v1, vv)`

Comment: doing Josilber suggestion i get following error "Error in integrate(f1, lower = 0, upper = vv/LCL_r, vv) : 
  maximum number of subdivisions reached
"

Comment: Your new error is completely unrelated to the original one -- a simple google search should suffice to get you going from here (or, failing that, a new R question _that shows your research in trying to solve the issue_).

Comment: You _should_ explain what is being attempted. Posting code without a natural language explanation is ineffective in the absence of Vulcan mind-melding capabilities over large distances.

Answer (score 0):

This doens't work because just as the error says, the functions `f1` and `f2` are really unaware of the `vv` value. It does not exist in a scope that they can access. The easiest fix is to pass `vv` as a parameter to the functions. The only catch with that is that R likes to pass vectors at a time to the function being integrated and each level of integration might not pass the same number of values so the lengths of `v1` and `v2` might not match the length of `vv` if you just pass it through directly. So To make sure we are operating on one value of `vv` at a time, we will make sure to `Vectorize` the `F_r` function. Here is one way to re-write the code

```
f1 <- function (v1, vv) {
    v1^(beta1-1)*exp(-(lambda1*v1)^beta1-(lambda0*(vv/LC-v1))^beta1)
}

f2 <- function (v2, vv) {
    v2^(beta1-1)*exp(-(lambda1*v2)^beta1-(lambda0*(vv/UC-v2))^beta1)
}

F_r <- Vectorize(function (vv) {
    (1+exp(-(lambda1*vv/LC)^beta1)-exp(-(lambda1*vv/UC)^beta1) 
      -beta1*lambda1^beta1* 
              ( integrate(f1,vv=vv,lower=0,upper=vv/LC)$value+
                integrate(f2,vv=vv,lower=0,upper=vv/UC)$value) )* 
              (b1^a1/gamma(a1))*vv^(a1-1)*exp(-b1*vv)
})

lambda0<-lambda1<-0.01
beta0<-beta1<-1
LC<-0.2
UC<-1.2
a1<-2
b1<-1

integrate(F_r,lower=0,upper=Inf)$value
```